# Error compiling generics with bounds

Tags: java, generics

I have a question on generics.

I have this snippet inside a class (let's call it case 1):

```
static {
    final List<Class<? extends A>> typeList = Arrays.asList(
        C.class,
        D.class
    );
}
```

and

```
public interface A {…}

public class C extends B {…}

public class D extends B {…}

public abstract class B implements A {…}
```

Android Studio complains and it doesn't compile on the line `final List…` above:

> Incompatible types
> Required List< **Class<? extends A>** >
> Found List< **Class<? extends B>** >

But, previously I had this code (let's call it case 2):

```
static {
    final List<Class<? extends A>> typeList = Arrays.asList(
        C.class,
        D.class
    );
}
```

and

```
public interface A {…}

public class C implements A {…}

public class D implements A {…}
```

and it compiled.

So, I tried, just for the sake of narrowing down the problem, changing case 1 into this:

```
static {
    final List<Class<? extends A>> typeList = Arrays.asList(
        B.class
    );
}
```

Please notice that B implements A, just like C and D in case two. But the compiler still complains.

I'm out of ideas to understand this problem, I read the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html) Types and Values chapter and still, nothing.

I searched at StackOverflow and I didn't find a similar question.

Any pointers? (PS: mandatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/138/) before someone does it)

Comment: Compiles fine for me. You can use an explicit type argument if you're using Java 7.

Comment: Sotiros Delimanolis, it's indeed a duplicate of that question, I guess I used the wrong terms to search before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is a problem of type inference.  Prior to Java 8, the compiler was not smart enough in its inference to use the type of `typeList` in determining the instantiation of `Arrays.asList`, so that happens in isolation.

Try this explicit hint:

```
final List<Class<? extends A>> typeList = Arrays.<Class<? extends A>>asList(
    B.class
);
```

To go into more detail, the compiler just sees this in isolation:

```
Arrays.asList(
    C.class,
    D.class
);
```

without seeing what it's assigned to.  It chooses `Class<? extends B>` instead of `Class<? extends A>`, as that is the most specific supertype common to all of the arguments.

Comment: It worked flawlessly! You were quick, so quick StackOverflow won't allow me to accept it yet! Thank you Mark Peters.